# Optional dependencies in webpack

Tags: require, ecmascript-6, webpack, ecmascript-2016

for example if I want to add `require("index.less")` to all files and ignore this line if the file does not exists.
how do I do it (including using of loaders for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended doing was improving the [imports loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader) to add an option to import a `less` file for every `jsx` file with the same name if it exists.

My improved `import loader`: https://github.com/welldone-software/imports-loader

The pull request: https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader/pull/12

For example dropping `mainview.less` in the same directory as `mainview.jsx`,  would add a `require("mainview.less")` import to the top of the `jsx` file:

```
loaders: [
    { test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['imports?null=[./{name}.less]', 'react-hot', 'babel'] },
    { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less' }
]
```

Answer (score 7):

One option would be to set up [require.context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) and then check if the file exists against that.

Rough idea:

```
var req = require.context('./', false, /^index.less$/);

if(req.keys().includes('./index.less')) {
  req('./index.less');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`imports-loader` with `includes` does the trick:

```js
{
  test: /\/index\.jsx$/,
  include: (modulePath) => fs.existsSync(path.join(path.dirname(modulePath), 'style.sass')),
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'imports-loader',
      options: {
        imports: 'side-effects ./style.sass'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```